# Xorg hangs before login screen

Tags: xorg, x11, fglrx

I'm using a TripleHead2Go to host 2 1920x1080 monitors as one massive 3840x1080 display in addition to my laptop's 1920x1200 display. If I try boooting with it plugged in, however, it hangs and never makes it to the login screen.

Things basically completely hang right before displaying the login screen; they seem to hang indefinitely. I have no idea why this adapter is causing things to hang. I was able to get the log by simply booting to a root shell and starting lightdm like so:

```
(sleep 30 && cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log ~/Desktop) & 
sudo service lightdm start
```

Here's the whole log, available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x1N9zGEu). The display is DFP1, I believe.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: You may need to post the full log somewhere. (you don't need to post screenshots of it, it's a text file)

Comment: I've posted the log on pastebin and updated the question. Hopefully that helps. If any more logs or testing on my port is required, please don't hesitate to ask.